# Does any Api in firefox OS support requestPermission() other than Notifications

Tags: api, firefox, permissions, firefox-os

I try to check if the user did not allow the permission for Contacts API and can i ask him again to grant the permission to my app using  requestPermission() like in Notifications API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission

```
var saving = navigator.mozContacts.save(person);
//Alert the user if the contact saved
saving.onsuccess = function() {
    alert('New contact saved');
};

//Get if there was error and display the message
saving.onerror = function(err) {
  if (err.target.error.name == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
    alert('Error: We need your permission to add new contact, please allow the app to add contacts');
  } else if (err.target.error.message) {
   alert('Error: ' + err.target.error.message);
  } else {
    alert('Error, Please contact us');
  }
};
```

I like in

```
if (err.target.error.name == 'PERMISSION_DENIED')
```

to ask the user again to allow the app using something similar to requestPermission()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requestPermission() API is specific to Notifications, is not universal.

The approach that may work for your case is to add specific user content to explain *why* you need the contact information.

Your code sample looks correct for detecting a permission denied state. In that part, perhaps you could then display an overlay which explains why the contact information is needed, and which features in your web app will not work without it.

You could also have some universally visible icon in your app that lets the user know that some functionality is not currently available because contacts data has not been accessed.